# Reading in a text file to be formatted and output (C programming)

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, formatting, char

I'm working a program for a class and it's proving much more difficult than I thought.
It's my very first experience with C, but I've had some experience with Java so I understand the general concepts.

***My goal:*** read in a text file that has some formatting requirements contained within the file, store the file in an array, apply the formatting and output the formatted text to stdout.

***The problem:*** reading in the file is easy, but I'm having trouble with the formatting and output.

***The challenge:***

--the input file will begin with **?width** X, **?mrgn** Y, or *both* (where X and Y are integers). these will always appear at the beginning of the file, and will each be on a separate line.

--the output must have the text formatted as per the formatting request (width, margin).

--additionally, there is a 3rd format command, **?fmt** on/off, which can appear multiple times at any point throughout the text and will turn formatting on/off.

--just a few catches: if no **?width** command appears, formatting is considered off and any **?margin** commands are ignored.

--if a **?width** command appears, formatting is considered on.

--the files can contain whitespace (as both tabs and spaces) which must be eliminated, but only when formatting is on.

--dynamic memory allocation is **not allowed**.

Easy for a first C program right? My professor is such a sweety.

I've been working on this code for hours (yes, I know it doesn't look like it) and I'm making little progress so if you feel like a challenge I would very much appreciate help of any kind. Thanks!

So far my code reads in the text file and formats the margin correctly. Can't seem to find a good way to eliminate whitespace (I believe tokenizing is the way to go) or do the word wrap when the length of the line is longer than the ?width command.

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <stdlib.h>
 3 #include <string.h>
 4 
 5 #define MAX_LINE_LEN 133 /* max 132 char per line plus one extra for the new line char
 6 #define MAX_LINES 300 /* max 300 lines per input file  */
 7 #define MAX_CHARS 39900 /* max number of characters in the file */
 8 
 9 /* Initializes array used to store lines read in from text
10    file as well as output array */
11 char input[MAX_LINE_LEN];
12 char buffer[MAX_CHARS];
13 char word_wrap[MAX_LINE_LEN];
14 
15 /* Functions */
16 void parameters(char [], FILE *);
17 
18 /* Variables */
19 int width = 0;
20 int margin = 0;
21 
22 /*
23 argc is the count of input arguments
24 *argv is a pointer to the input arguments
25 */
26 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
27 {
28     /* Creates file pointer */
29     FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* r for read */
30 
31     if (!fp) /* Error checking */
32     {
33         printf("Error: Could not open file");
34         return 0;
35     }
36         
37     /* Retrieves width and margin parameters from input file */
38     parameters(input, fp);
39 
40     fclose(fp);     /* Closes file stream */
41 
42     return 0;
43 }
44 
45 void parameters(char input[], FILE *fp)
46 {
47     /* Gets input file text line by line */
48     while (fgets (input, 133, fp) != NULL)
49     {
50         /* Creates a pointer to traverse array */
51         char *p = input;
52 
53         /* Checks for width parameter read in from text file */
54         if (input[0] == '?' && input [1] == 'w')
55         {
56                 strtok(input, " ");    /* Eliminates first token '?width'    */
57                 width = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));    /* Stores int value of ASCII token
58                 p = NULL;
59         }
60 
61         /* Checks for margin parameter read in from text file */
62         if (input[0] == '?' && input[1] == 'm')
63         {
64             strtok(input, " ");                  /* Eliminates first token '?mrgn' */
65             margin = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));    /* Stores int value of ASCII token
66             p = NULL;
67         }
68 
69         if (p != NULL)      /* skips printing format tokens at beginning of file */
70         {
71             if (width == 0)     /* no width command, formatting is off by default */
72             {
73                 printf("%s", p); /* Prints unformatted line of text */
74             }
75             else    /* formatting is on */
76             {
77                 printf("%*s" "%s", margin, " ",  p); /* Prints formatted line of text
78             }
79         }
80     }
81 }
82
```

And here's an example input file, along with its proper output:

```
?width 30
?mrgn 5
While there    are enough characters   here to
fill
    at least one line, there is
plenty
of
            white space which will cause
a bit of confusion to the reader, yet
the ?fmt off command means  that
    the original formatting of
the lines
    must be preserved. In essence, the
command ?pgwdth is ignored.
```

Output:

```
     While there are enough
     characters here to fill
     at least one line, there
     is plenty of white space
     which will cause a bit of
     confusion to the reader,
     yet the ?fmt off command means  that
         the original formatting of
the lines
    must be preserved. In essence, the
command ?pgwdth is ignored.
```

Comment: you might be better off using sscanf?